# Debugging JavaScriptCore heap crashes in Big Sur

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, javascriptcore

I have a JavaScriptCore scripting interface in my app, with access to some subclasses, which can be initialized in `JSContext`.

After migrating to Big Sur, I'm getting constant crashes after the context has already been abandoned and all of the code evaluated. Crashes are both general protection faults (`EXC_I386_GPFLT`) and more general bad access errors (ie. `Heap Helper Thread (30): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7ffdde3bdf0`). Some errors are at very low addresses, like `0x18`.

Parser code

```
self.vm = [[JSVirtualMachine alloc] init];
self.context = [[JSContext alloc] initWithVirtualMachine:_vm];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.context evaluateScript:script];
});
```

The errors happen when using a custom `NSPanel` subclass via `JavaScriptCore`.

`PluginWindow.h` with only the relevant code:

```
-(instancetype)initWithHTML:(NSString*)html width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height delegate:(id)delegate {
    self = [super initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskUtilityWindow | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable | NSWindowStyleMaskTitled backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    self.delegate = delegate;
    return self;
}
```

The subclass can then be initialized through JavaScript:

```
let htmlWindow = App.htmlWindow()
```

The host (owner of both VM and context) should be terminated once the window closes. This operation can be done **once**, but for some reason, initializing a new class and nulling the old one causes the crash.

Is there a way to create some sort of protections against JavaScriptCore bad access faults, and how do I effectively debug these errors?

Comment: Is this issue related to [Crash when closing NSPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080170/crash-when-closing-nspanel)? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Not related, though it did overlap a bit. I have a reproducible example, but the behavior is *very* random, and on a good day the problem doesn't get reproduced. However, I might have found a solution and will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to a conflict between ARC and `JavaScriptCore`. ARC has already disposed of the object, while its reference still exists in `JSContext`.

I ran some tests and sometimes the bug could activate after 45 minutes or so, with the app being completely idle. I'm pretty sure that when JS garbage collection activates, it tries to access something that has already been wiped out of memory by ARC.

I managed to fix this by being careful to not null anything, and retaining weak references to everything I am initializing via JS.

I am not sure if this is a bug or not, and recreating similar scheme in Swift **does not** result in crashes, as far as I can tell. Pre-Big Sur systems don't seem to be affected.